# installing gorm in windows for objective c gui

Tags: objective-c

I have installed msys, core and devel from gnustep.org. I'm interested in gui of objective c. As per my understanding I need gorm for that. I downloaded gorm but I'm not sure where I should extract it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [wiki](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Gorm_Installation_On_Windows) page, the build needs to be done in `Go to the Gorm directory under gnustep/dev-apps/Gorm`. I would suggest you to follow the steps given on the web page I have mentioned.
The steps are as follows:

1. Install mingw as described here: [Installation on Windows](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/Installation_on_Windows)
2. Go to the Gorm directory under gnustep/dev-apps/Gorm
3. Executing the following commands:

   - ### First build the InterfaceBuilder library...

     `ln -s GormLib InterfaceBuilder

     cd InterfaceBuilder

     make install`
   - ### Now build Gorm itself...

     `cd ../

     make`
   - ### Now install the palettes into the app and install

     `make install`

### For Gorm versions after 0.9.5 (CVS) or release 0.9.10

As of version 0.9.10 of Gorm, the build requires no special consideration. The above page is obsolete for these versions of Gorm. Simply doing a "make install" from the command line in the MinGW shell on Windows in the Gorm directory should install Gorm correctly.